# Mendelson's 4.5 Proposition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

There is a proposition:
$M(X) \Rightarrow \exists(Z), M(Z) \land X\in Z$

I know how to prove it using Pairing Axiom. ($X\in\{X,X\}$ and $M(\{X,X\})$)

But I saw somewhere the different proof, without Pairing Axiom. 
What can it be?

---

$M(X):=$"X is a set"$=\exists Y,X\in Y$.

Both variants are good and worth the upvotes, but I saw a different proof. (It was really great and, probably, no axioms from set theory was used. Just predicate calculus axioms, Bernays rules, Modus Ponens and magic. )

[image]

Comment: $M(X)$ therefore $M(P(X))$, and $X\in P(X)$ (use Axiom W (Power Set))

Comment: What is $M$? Just any formula?

Comment: $M(X)$ iff $\exists Z: X \in Z$ ($M(X)$:= $X$ is Set)

Comment: Thanks. Well, would be good to put that in the question. People shouldn't need to look into the book to see the definition.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to avoid the Pairing axiom, you can use Replacement and Infinity to form
$$ \{ F(y) \mid y\in\omega \} $$
where $F(y)=X$ for every $y$.

---

Alternatively, as martin.koeberl points, out $\mathcal P(X)$ is always a set that has $X$ as an element.

Comment: There's still Power Set.

Comment: @martin.koeberl: Hmm, right. Edited.